# How to deploy a databricks notebook with Terraform and ADO approval gate?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, yaml, terraform-provider-azure

Curerntly I have the following yml code that deploys a databricks instance to Azure via Terraform successfully:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
variables:
  - group: terraform-databricks-test

steps:
- task: TerraformInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install Terraform'
  inputs:
    terraformVersion: 'latest'

- checkout: self
  displayName: 'Checkout repository'

- task: TerraformTaskV4@0
  displayName: 'Terraform Init'
  inputs:
    command: 'init'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/terraform'
    backendType: 'azurerm'
    ensureBackend: true
    backendServiceArm: 'test-SPN'
    backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'test-group'
    backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'accountName'
    backendAzureRmContainerName: 'containerName'
    backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform.tfstate'

- task: TerraformTaskV3@3
  displayName: 'Terraform Validate'
  inputs:
    command: 'validate'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

- task: TerraformTaskV3@3
  displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
  inputs:
    command: 'plan'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/terraform'
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'test-SPN'

- task: TerraformTaskV3@3
  displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
  inputs:
    command: 'apply'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/terraform'
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'test-SPN'
```

What I want is to add some "approval gate" from Azure DevOps, so when the plan is successful then a user can approve the new changes that will be applied. The approval gate is simply an environment that you can create through ADO, then you select the users who will be approving. To link this gate in the terraform code you need the keyword `environment` in the yml file.

I have the following code that tries to run with the approval gate. The first stage complets successfully, but the second stage fails with the error: `There was an error when attempting to execute the process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/1.6.5/x64/terraform'. This may indicate the process failed to start. Error: spawn /opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/1.6.5/x64/terraform ENOENT`

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - group: terraform-databricks

stages:
  - stage: PlanAndValidate
    jobs:
   - job: PlanAndValidate
     steps:
      - task: TerraformInstaller@0
        displayName: 'Install Terraform'

      - task: TerraformTaskV4@0
        displayName: 'Terraform Init'
        inputs:
          command: 'init'
          workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/terraform'
          backendType: 'azurerm'
          ensureBackend: true
          backendServiceArm: 'test-SPN'
          backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'test-group'
          backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'accountName'
          backendAzureRmContainerName: 'containerName'
          backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform.tfstate'

      - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
        displayName: 'Terraform Validate'
        inputs:
          command: 'validate'
          workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

      - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
        displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
        inputs: 
          command: 'plan'
          workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/terraform'
          environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'test-SPN'

  - stage: Apply
    jobs:
    - deployment: Apply
      displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
        environment: databricks-env
        strategy:
         runOnce:
          deploy:
           steps:
            - task: TerraformInstaller@0
              displayName: 'Install Terraform'

            - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
              displayName: 'Terraform apply'
              inputs:
                command: 'apply'
                workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/terraform'
                environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'test-SPN'
```

I have a few questions:

1. I have tried to remove the convoluted `strategy` `runOnce` keywords and left the `environment` but it seems this latter depends on the previous keywords. Is this really the case?
2. The error might indicate there is something wrong with the directory path. Possibly, the terraform files are not found and that's why the error arises. If this is the case then how should I define my path in the second part of the stage to apply the changes?

Feel free to improve this question or to request additional clarifications :)

Comment: First step in troubleshooting YAM is to tick "enable system diagnostics" which we give you verbose output and possible shed some light on the issue. It might be worth just creating a very simple repro with just a single stage without the environment/approval, as this doesn't appear to relate to the core issue (terraform won't run)

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to remove the convoluted strategy runOnce keywords and left the environment but it seems this latter depends on the previous keywords. Is this really the case?

Please check the [jobs.deployment.strategy.runOnce definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-deployment-strategy-run-once?view=azure-pipelines). The runOnce deployment strategy rolls out changes by executing each of its steps one time.

> The error might indicate there is something wrong with the directory path. Possibly, the terraform files are not found and that's why the error arises. If this is the case then how should I define my path in the second part of the stage to apply the changes?

You can add `'Terraform Init'` task in the second stage.  In each job, there should be `'Install Terraform'` and `'Terraform Init'` task before the other Terraform commands, since each job will run on a new agent.

By the way, here is the [Terraform starter project for Azure Pipelines](https://github.com/microsoft/terraform-azure-devops-starter/tree/master) for your reference.